# How to associate a file extension to be opened with a batch script?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, batch, file-extension

I want to get rid of OSPPSVC (Office Software Protection Platform Service).

Then, I have replaced the links to open Office programs with a link to `launcher.bat`:

```
@echo off
title Launching Office...
Set target=%1

sc config osppsvc start= demand
net start osppsvc

:check
if exist "%target%.exe" goto launch
Set/p target="Introduce the program to open:"
goto check

:launch
start %target%.exe %2

sleep 10

sc config osppsvc start= disabled
net stop osppsvc
```

And I can open files if, in the console, I enter:

```
"C:\Path\To\Office14\launcher.bat" winword "C:\Path\To\File\doc.docx"
```

But, since I want explorer integration, I have tried associating `.docx` extension to be opened with

```
"C:\Path\To\Office14\launcher.bat" winword "%1"
```

But it doesn't work: the batch file runs but doesn't open Word (it asks "Introduce the program to open:").

---

**Edit**: Fixed code:

```
@echo off
title Launching Office...
Set name=%1

sc config osppsvc start= demand
net start osppsvc

:check
Set target="%~dp0%name%.exe"
if exist %target% goto launch
Set/p name="Introduce the program to open:"
goto check

:launch
start "" %target% %2

sleep 10

sc config osppsvc start= disabled
net stop osppsvc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it appears that you need to specify which folder %target% is in, unless somehow the Office path is in your %PATH%.

Comment: But if `launcher.bat` is in the Office folder, shouldn't it work?

Comment: Not necessarily. You may want to test to see what the script sees as its working directory when its called. It's probably working from the directory where %1 is.